# 'svn' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: svn, maven, cmd

When i am trying to build my maven application on net beans IDE i am get this error, can any please help me out.

```
Checking for local modifications: skipped.
Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "svn --non-interactive update D:\server"
Working directory: D:\server
Provider message:
The svn command failed.
Command output:
'svn' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 2.070s
Finished at: Mon Dec 17 19:24:19 IST 2012
Final Memory: 15M/175M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:buildnumber-maven-plugin:1.1:create (default) on project red5-server: Couldn't update project. Error! -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: svn command is not set properly in your `PATH` environment varialble. Set PATH to /bin folder of svn client.

Comment: Either add svn to your %PATH% env variable (if you have it installed) or download and install SVN. See the official binary packages list at http://subversion.apache.org/packages.html#windows

Answer (score 13):

I see you're executing this line:

```
cmd.exe /X /C "svn --non-interactive update D:\server
```

That means there is no `svn.bat` or `svn` found in any directories set in your %PATH% variable.

Do you have Subversion installed on your Windows system? If you used the CollabNet version of Subversion, it should have automatically updated your PATH to include `C:\Program Files\Subversion\bin` or something similar in your %PATH% variable. If not, open the System Control Panel, go to the *Advanced* tab, and click on *Set Environment Variables*. Find the PATH environment variable and add the directory where the `svn.exe` program is located.

If you haven't installed Subversion, install it from either CollabNet, SlikSVN, or Wandisco.

Comment: Or SVN command-line tools from VisualSVN: http://www.visualsvn.com/downloads/ ;) lol

Answer (score 10):

You should perhaps use the `javasvn` provider. That way your build/release won't depend on a local installation of an SVN client and setting env variables.

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>    
                <groupId>com.google.code.maven-scm-provider-svnjava</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-scm-provider-svnjava</artifactId>
                <version>1.6</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <configuration>
            <providerImplementations>
                <svn>javasvn</svn>
            </providerImplementations>
            <goals>deploy</goals>
            <tagBase>https://svn.somedomain/project/tags</tagBase>
            <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
            <tagNameFormat>project-@{project.version}</tagNameFormat>
        </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: I am getting same error . I am using release plugin version 2.5.3 , but no option to declare com.google.code.maven-scm-provider-svnjava dependancy.  any suggestions