# 'svn' is not recognized as an internal or external command -maven-release-plugin eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, svn

I am trying to perform   maven release prepare from eclipse .

pom.xml

```
       <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <providerImplementations>
                    <svn>javasvn</svn>
                </providerImplementations>
                <goals>deploy</goals>
                <tagBase>https://svn.somedomain/project/tags</tagBase>
                <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
                <tagNameFormat>project-@{project.version}
                </tagNameFormat>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Error on release:prepare

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.3.2:prepare (default-cli) on project util: Unable to check for local modifications
[ERROR] Provider message:
[ERROR] The svn command failed.
[ERROR] Command output:
[ERROR] 'svn' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
[ERROR] operable program or batch file.
```

I do not have native svn client installed. I wanted to use javasvn .
Any sugestions

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15785453/6565719) helps?

Comment: No, I am not able to specify  dependencies inside the plugin